# Trouble 'generating' bash aliases

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, bash-alias

In my `~/.shortcuts`, I have symlinks to some frequently used directories.

In `.bashrc` (OS X), I am doing this:

`ls -1 ~/.shortcuts | xargs -I {} alias {}="'cd -P ~/.shortcuts/{}'"`

When I run `alias` in the terminal, the output *shows* the newly added aliases **but none of the aliases work. Why?**

I have some aliases like `alias ll='ls -l'` defined in `.bash_aliases`. Doing `. ~/.bash_aliases` in `.bashrc` loads my custom aliases perfectly well. But, when I redirect the `xargs -t` output to a tmp file and source it in bashrc (just like I source `.bash_aliases`), it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because that `alias` is run in a subshell that exits immediately after that. It never affects the shell that started the pipeline.

You should try something like:

```
for short in ~/.shortcuts/* ; do
  alias $(basename $short)="cd -P $short"
done
```

This assumes you have no files with funny characters (like whitespace) in their names in that folder.

(Generally speaking, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use your shell's globbing functions.)

Comment: About the second part of the question: I'm guessing, sourcing the file with aliases did not work because I was parsing the output of ls?

Comment: No, more likely some quoting problems I guess. Would have to see the exact contents of that file to know exactly.